# TraditionalForm for Inactive Limit, with Direction, broken

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, output-formatting, hold

Whereas:

```
Inactivate[Limit[Sin[x],x->0,Direction->-1],Limit]//TraditionalForm
```

produces the expected result,

```
Inactivate[Limit[Sin[x],x->0,Direction->+1],Limit]//TraditionalForm
```

ignores the `TraditionalForm` .

Why??  A workaround, please?

Thanx.  (version: 11.0.1.0, Student Edition)

Comment: It looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 5):

```
Limit[Sin[x], x -> 0, Direction -> +1] // HoldForm // TraditionalForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

It looks like a bug.  Here is the limit that works:

```
Inactivate[Limit[Sin[x], x -> 0, Direction -> -1], Limit] // TraditionalForm
(* boxes:
  Cell[BoxData[
   FormBox[
    TemplateBox[{RowBox[{"sin", "(", "x", ")"}],"x","0","InactiveTraditional"},
     "InactiveLimitFromRight"], TraditionalForm]], "Output",
   CellChangeTimes->{3.692388994988666*^9}]
*)
```

For the other limit, the `TemplateBox` tag should be changed to `"InactiveLimitFromLeft"`, and everything would work.  Instead, we get this:

```
Inactivate[Limit[Sin[x], x -> 0, Direction -> +1], Limit] // TraditionalForm
(*
  Cell[BoxData[
   FormBox[
    RowBox[{
     TemplateBox[{"Limit"},
      "InactiveHead",
      BaseStyle->"InactiveTraditional",
      SyntaxForm->"Symbol",
      Tooltip->"Inactive[Limit]"], "[", 
     RowBox[{
      RowBox[{"sin", "(", "x", ")"}], ",", 
      RowBox[{"x", "->", "0"}], ",", 
      RowBox[{"Direction", "->", "1"}]}], "]"}], TraditionalForm]], "Output",
   CellChangeTimes->{3.692388970749687*^9, 3.69238922897786*^9}]
*)
```

Comment: thanx. I had noticed that the `HoldForm[]`s would work, but I actually have a much more complex function than `Sin[x]`, and want only the `Limit[]` to be `Inactive[]`.  BTW, do the WR people look here for such bugs, or is one to report it elsewhere?

Comment: You should report bugs to WRI (from the menu Help > Give Feedback). There are some employees who look here and answer, but the official policy is that users should report issues.